# How to launch swipe event "manually"?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can we launch the swipe Jquery event manually (like `$('div').click();` for the click event) ?

`$('div').live('swipeleft');` doesn't enables to do it.

Comment: Which swipe jQuery event? You are using a custom jQuery plugin, I believe. What about `$('div').trigger('swipeleft');`?

Comment: `$.trigger()` is what i need, maybe you could duplicate this comment as an answer so i could valide it.
Thanks.

Comment: Perfect. There you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending of the implementation of the plugin you are working with, normally you could use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to programmatically execute the `swipeleft` event handlers with a synthetic event.

```
$('div').trigger('swipeleft');
```